# How to re-run/reload a section of a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following Angular controller, the `$q.all` gets a JSON tree which is saved in `$scope.building`. `$scope.building` is then used to create `pano`'s and `panodata`'s:

**JS:**

```
angular.module('yoApp')
  .controller('addPanoCtrl', function($q, $scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, serviceUpload) {
    $scope.buildingId = $routeParams.buildingId

    $q.all([
      serviceUpload.getAllBuilding()
    ]).then(function(value) {
      var buildingJSON = _.where(JSON.parse(value), {'objectId': $scope.buildingId})
      $scope.building = buildingJSON[0]
    }, function(reason) {
      $scope.result = reason
    })

    // Methods

    $scope.addPano = function() {
      // SOME CODE
      pano.save(json, {
    success: function(object) {
      $scope.building.pano.push(json)
      $scope.panoName = ''
      $scope.$digest()
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
    }
      })
    }

    $scope.addPanodata = function(panoId) {
      // SOME CODE
      panodata.save(json, {
    success: function(object) {
      $scope.pano.panoData.push(json)
      $scope.panodataName = ''
      $scope.$digest()
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
    }
      })
    }
  })
```

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="pano in building.pano">
    <!-- SOME CODE -->
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:;" ng-click="addPanodata(pano.objectId)">Add</a>
```

Saving `pano`'s has no problem since I have `$scope.buildingId`. The problem arises when I save a `panodata`. If I create a `pano` and then a `panodata` I can't since `$scope.building` doesn't have the new `pano`.

The `panodata` is saved if I reload the page, but I was thinking if there's away to reload only the `$q.all` bit so `$scope.building` get's fetched again with the newly created `pano`.

What's the common way to accomplish this in AngularJS?

Comment: Hi, put your [$q.all(..)] in a function , at the first, call that function to run and then call that function every where you want to reload your scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract getting the data into a function and then call it again when you need to update the data, e.g. inside of `$scope.addPanodata()`